# Calling method on autowired controller hangs when executed on a new thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a very simplified code sample below, but basically I have a scheduler that calls a controller on a new thread.  In that new thread MOST autowired beans work fine, but one of them, MyController, just hangs if i try and invoke it for any reason. The only thing i can find different about MyController to the other autowired objects is that it is 'EnhancerbyspringCGLIB' which I suspect is the problem.  I must be doing something stupid or losing context by creating a new thread and it then cannot resolve a proxy or something? I am lost though so any pointers would be appreciated!

Note, if I call the method directly instead of from a new thread all works fine, but I cannot do this as its test code which bypasses event handling and I need to make sure there is no stale java objects in memory.

Sample code:

```
@Primary
@Component
public class Scheduler {
    @Autowired MyController controller;
    void myMethod(){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            controller.doSomething();
        });
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Controller
public class MyController{
    doSomething(){
        //I will never get here
    }
}
```